# Reductions in Algorithms

Tags: analysis, computer-science, computational-complexity, np-complete

From what I currently understand about reductions,

If an algorithm A <= B, then we know that given an algorithm B, we can solve the algorithm A.

Based on this definition, in my notes, it states that A is therefore "easier" then B, and that A yields a lower bound for B.

Why is it the case that A is "easier" if we are technically using B, and thus A should be a more complex problem or a special case of B where more work can be done? And since we're using B, shouldn't B provide the lower bound for A instead of the other way around?

Thank you!

Comment: This was asked recently on the CS StackExchange: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/83903/the-directionality-of-reductions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $A$ and $B$ are problems, not algorithms.  The actual definition says that $A \leq B$ if we can use an algorithm that solves problem $B$ to solve problem $A$.  (We also require that the translation that may be necessary to do so be "cheap.")

Suppose you have a program that solves CNF SAT in its more general form.  You can certainly use that program to solve an instance of 2-SAT.  Suppose you have an algorithm that solves 2-SAT.  How would you use it to solve instances of CNF SAT in which clauses have more than 2 literals?  Here CNF SAT is $B$ and 2-SAT is $A$.  Clearly $A$ is easier than $B$.

Now consider 3-SAT.  Once again, you can use your algorithm for CNF SAT to solve any instance of 3-SAT.  Since 3-SAT is NP-complete, CNF SAT, which is easily seen to be in NP, is also NP-complete.  (If CNF SAT could be solved in deterministic polynomial time, so would 3-SAT.)  Therefore $A$ (3-SAT) has provided a lower bound for $B$ (CNF SAT).

Finally, if you have an algorithm for 3-SAT you can solve all instances of CNF SAT, though this time you may need some work to obtain an instance of 3-SAT whose answer will give you the answer to the instance of CNF SAT.  The amount of work required is small, though (polynomial, to be precise) and so we conclude that CNF SAT is fundamentally no more difficult than 3-SAT.

Note that it is possible for $A \leq B$ and $B \leq A$ to both hold.  Translating $A \leq B$ into "$A$ is easier than $B$" may initially be the cause of some discomfort, because in non-mathematical talk we think of "easier" as a strict inequality.  After the initial discomfort, though, we begin to appreciate the conciseness.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response. I'm still a little bit confused but I'd like to give a try at a reduction, do you mind letting me know if it makes sense? 
For example if I have the independent set problem and i'd like to reduce it to 3SAT. so INDEPENDENT SET ≤ 3SAT. Now given an algorithm for 3SAT, I can solve the decision problem for INDEPENDENT SET. But here, I now conclude that independent set is "easier" then 3 SAT? I'm still confuse as to how this is now "easier" event though I've used 3SAT in order to solve INDEPENDENT SET

Comment: Try replacing "easier" wiith "no harder than."  If you can solve INDEPENDENT SET once you've learned how to solve 3-SAT, the former is no harder than the second, right? For a different perspective, think of computing the area of a convex polygon.  There are formulae for that and you can clearly use them to compute the area of a square.  However, if you only know how to compute the area of a square, can you compute the area of any convex polygon?  Which problem is easier?

Comment: Finally, think of your definition of special case.  Part of your confusion may come from there.  If $A$ is a special case of $B$, every instance of $A$ is also an instance of $B$, but some instances of $B$ are not instances of $A$.  If you have a method that works for all instances of $B$, it works also for all instances of $A$, though there may be more efficient ways to solve instances of $A$.  Knowing that a graph has no negative edge lengths allows you to solve the shortest path problem more efficiently than in the general case, but you can still use Bellman-Ford.

Comment: Ah I see, the second comment really helped with the special case analogy. As a follow-up does this mean all np-complete problems are just special cases of the original Circuit SAT or even 3SAT, since reductions are transitive?

Comment: Every NP-complete problem is polynomially reducible to every NP-complete problem. Specifically, every NP-complete problem is reducible to CIRCUIT SAT and to 3-SAT.  But it's also true that CIRCUIT SAT and 3-SAT are polynomially reducible to every NP-complete problem.  In this case I would not say that every NP-complete problem is a special case of a chosen NP-complete problem.  I'd leave that claim for cases like 2-SAT and 3-SAT being special cases of CNF SAT.